How Configure team city to build different dot net framework applications with its agents
If will migrate applications from dotnet framework 4.5 to dotnet framework 4.8. So, Now if there are few applications on dotnet 4.5 still and few on dotnet 4.8 framework.
I'd like to know if there is any way we can have multiple dotnet framework version on a single agent and can specify it as part of the build configuration in team city or not ?
Any reference would help to setup it if possible in Team city ?
didn't get answer on feasibility yet
